# Android - TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, exception

> Exception thrown launching activities in ProcessRecord{3c67ecf8080:com.example/u0a171}
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 572488 bytes

**Passing data**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SearchListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(HRConstants.SEARCHLIST, searchResponse);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Getting Data**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
searchResponse = intent.getParcelableExtra(HRConstants.SEARCHLIST);
searchLists = searchResponse.getSearchResults();
```

My `minSdkVersion` is 15 and `targetSdkVersion` is 26.

The response contained 1736 items followed by an exception. It works fine with fewer items.

Comment: Read this https://www.neotechsoftware.com/blog/android-intent-size-limit

Comment: save your list in static list and acess it in other activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because intents in Android can carry no more than 1MB of data. A workaround would be puting "searchResult" inside a public static object

```
Intent intent=new Intent(activity,SearchListActivity.class);
//intent.putExtra(HRConstants.SEARCHLIST,  searchResponse);
YourActivity.SearchResponse = searchResponse;
startActivity(intent);
```

In the SearchListActivity, instead of doing

```
getIntent.getExtras();
```

you can access your object now saved into

```
List<Search> list = YourActivity.SeachResponse;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround as I said, FYI @Myself check if the object is not null. If your activity was destroyed the object will no longer remain in memory.
Answer with the good practice  please.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra() instead of putExtra(), and getParcelableArrayListExtra() instead of getParcelableExtra(). You can lose the casts as well, that may be where it's blowing up